# panda read row value from dataframe if condition match and also read any previous row whenever condition match

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, date

Please help me to find the solution of below.

I have a csv file (2 different sample of same csv, only difference in Error_2 column  values)-

CSV A(Sample -1)-

```
 Timestamp          Date/Time            Error_1            Error_2                 Error_3
170:02:46:928    2023/01/01 16:45:13     APP_ERR         Loss_of_Data               NO_ERROR 
170:14:40:928    2023/01/01 16:57:08     APP_ERR         Loss_of_Data               NO_ERROR 
170:28:16:928    2023/01/01 17:10:44     APP_ERR         Loss_of_Data               NO_ERROR 
170:28:37:328    2023/01/01 17:11:04     APP_ERR         SB_Data_Expiration         Loss_of_Data 
170:29:57:728    2023/01/01 17:12:24     APP_ERR         PEB_due_to_overlimit       Due_to_Over_SBI 
170:32:59:978    2023/01/01 17:15:27     APP_ERR         Cnx_Attempt                NO_ERROR 
170:33:40:778    2023/01/01 17:16:08     APP_ERR         Cnx_Attempt                NO_ERROR
```

CSV A(Sample -2)-

```
 Timestamp          Date/Time            Error_1            Error_2                 Error_3
170:02:46:928    2023/01/01 16:45:13     APP_ERR         Loss_of_Data               NO_ERROR 
170:14:40:928    2023/01/01 16:57:08     APP_ERR         Loss_of_Data               NO_ERROR 
170:28:16:928    2023/01/01 17:10:44     APP_ERR         Cnx_Attempt                NO_ERROR 
170:28:37:328    2023/01/01 17:11:04     APP_ERR         SB_Data_Expiration         Loss_of_Data 
170:29:57:728    2023/01/01 17:12:24     APP_ERR         PEB_due_to_overlimit       Due_to_Over_SBI 
170:32:59:978    2023/01/01 17:15:27     APP_ERR         Cnx_Attempt                NO_ERROR 
170:33:40:778    2023/01/01 17:16:08     APP_ERR         Cnx_Attempt                NO_ERROR
```

I want to read the row values(few columns) if below condition match -

Error_2 = 'SB_Data_Expiration' and Error_3 = 'Loss_of_Data'

also want to add one more date column(previous row Date/time) if condition match i.e. Error_2='Loss_of_Data'(it can be previous row or previous to previous row)

Final dataframe output I am looking for is -

Output from Sample 1 -

```
Date/Time                Error_1            Error_2                 Error_3         Previous_Date/Time 
2023/01/01 17:11:04      APP_ERR         SB_Data_Expiration         Loss_of_Data    2023/01/01 17:10:44
```

Output from Sample 2 -

```
Date/Time                Error_1            Error_2                 Error_3         Previous_Date/Time 
2023/01/01 17:11:04      APP_ERR         SB_Data_Expiration         Loss_of_Data    2023/01/01 16:57:08
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the CSV file and filter rows that match the given conditions. Then, you can create a new column containing the previous date/time value and finally, create a new dataframe containing only the desired columns.

```
# filter rows that match the given conditions
mask = (df['Error_2'] == 'SB_Data_Expiration') & (df['Error_3'] == 
'Loss_of_Data') 
filtered_df = df.loc[mask]

# create a new column containing the previous date/time value
filtered_df['Previous_Date/Time'] = filtered_df['Date/Time'].shift(1)

# create a new dataframe containing only the desired columns
output_df = filtered_df[['Previous_Date/Time', 'Date/Time', 'Error_1', 
'Error_2', 'Error_3']]
```

Comment: Hi @LoneWalkerNS, thanks for the reply but your solution didn't work because how we will shift from 'filtered_df' as it will have only one row, second we need to check the 'Error_2='Loss_of_Data'' condition in the previous row.